# How to delete all occurrences of .BackupManager and BackupManager.list from C:\ drive on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I just bought an Acer Aspire 5551. Nifty little laptop, great price.

Last night, I tried Acer Backup Manager for the first time. Besides taking hellish long (compared to SyncBack), it also created a folder .BackupManager in every folder on my C:\ drive!!! What a mess. I would like to delete all occurrences of this folder, and the files inside.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: yes, a complete mess this Backup Manager. Thanks for the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search (Win-F) for .BackupManager and delete all instances you find from the search result.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be showing any results. The folders are set to 'hidden'. Is there a way to make hidden folders appear in search results too?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I had to open C:\ folder, and search from there. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You might need to delete the .BackupManager files in safe mode, if you receive error 0x80004002. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Install Fast Duplicate File Finder. Search for 'similar file names'. It will find all the BackupManager.list files. Send them to the recycling bin for checking, as it seems to scoop up innocent bystanders too.